# MySQL - Indexing Partitioned Column

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table with no primary key defined, partitioned on a column, using List Partitioning method. It has huge data in one partition. Though partitioned column is used in WHERE clause while querying against this table, performance is very slow.

Is it suggestible to create an index that includes the partitioned column? Here's my sample table structure,

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   AccountId BIGINT,
   AccountNumber VARCHAR(250),
   DeviceId BIGINT,
   DeviceNumber VARCHAR(250),
   ClientId SMALLINT
   CreatedDate DATETIME,
   CreatedUser VARCHAR(50)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (ClientId)
 (PARTITION p_1 VALUES IN (1),
  PARTITION p_2 VALUES IN (2),
  PARTITION p_3 VALUES IN (3),
  PARTITION p_4 VALUES IN (4),
  PARTITION p_5 VALUES IN (5),
  PARTITION p_6 VALUES IN (6),
  PARTITION p_7 VALUES IN (7),
  PARTITION p_8 VALUES IN (8),
  PARTITION p_9 VALUES IN (9),
  PARTITION p_10 VALUES IN (10),
  PARTITION p_11 VALUES IN (11),
  PARTITION p_12 VALUES IN (12),
  PARTITION p_13 VALUES IN (13),
  PARTITION p_14 VALUES IN (14),
  PARTITION p_15 VALUES IN (15));
```

Table is partitioned by "ClientId" and I had to make 1024 partitions to this table.

Comment: try to use explain extended(maybe explain extend), it will shows the execute plan with partitions;

Comment: @GreenBlade My query is using the right partition. The problem is even in the single partition data is huge. I'll edit my question :)

Comment: create a index include the partitioned column is OK, if your queries doesn't update the partitioned colum too often, try the "alter" statement and slow query in test env before do it in production env; Old versions of MySQL may block DML when add the index, be careful~ :D

Comment: Doesn't it affect INSERT operations? Everyday data is inserted into the table by truncating that partition!

Comment: You mean the partition table is truncated everyday and insert new data?

Comment: Yes, but not the entire table. A single partition gets truncated.

Comment: "Alter table truncate partition"  needs the metadata lock, any INSERT operation should block the "Alter table truncate partition", no matter the table has index include partitioned column or not;

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186500/mysql-indexing-partitioned-column , which I have already answered.